# twitter API search/tweets - How to filter to search user-relevant tweets using query operator?

Tags: search, twitter, twitter-oauth

The default is apparently to search all public tweets. I am trying to use the search API to return tweets from only the user's followers, or from the user's "twitterfeed", or both. In the search manual (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) it says I am able to include a "query operator" of source:twitterfeed to accomplish the latter. I have tried this on the twitter website search form, and it works, or at least it does something. When I try it with my API search, I get no results. No error, no results. My API search works fine without it. I do url-encode the query operator and I have tried adding it in front or behind my search query.

Here is an example path I have tried:

```
/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=source%253Atwitterfeed%2520fg&count=7&result_type=recent
```

Also on the twitter search page there is an optional parameter "f=follows" which allows you to search only followers. Can I use this with the API? I have tried using it directly and it did not have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think source means what you think it does.  "Source" in this case refers to where the user generated the tweet.  Sources might be "web", "TweetDeck", "Twitter for iOS", etc.

I think what you really want is to search a user's timeline.  https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: OK. So there is no direct way to do that from the API I guess, I have to implement it myself. Thanks.